# Is AWS S3 only for file storage? Can I use it to store a list of complex objects?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am brand new to AWS S3. Right now, one idea to store intermediate results of our project is to save it into S3. But when I google online, it seems most likely S3 is for file storage.

I am wondering if it is something that can be used to save complex entities. If it can, is it a good idea (design) to use it for storing entities. For example, creating an api for others to insert (bulk/single) objects into S3?

Comment: It's a storage for binary objects. You _could_ use it for "complex entities", but it sounds like you want some sort of database.

Comment: Amazon S3 can store _anything_. The question is... how do you want to _access_ the data afterwards?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I saw something like "listObjects". Let's say when I put a list of "complex entities" as object 1 at time 1, and then put another list of "complex entities" as object 2 at time 2 in the same bucket. When I listObjects, will I get two lists back? Thanks.

Comment: You'd need to look at the access pattern for your stored data in order to answer this question. Yes you can store complex entities, for example by storing JSON within objects in S3. You can also select and return the content from objects on the basis of their JSON content using a feature called S3 Select (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/selecting-content-from-objects.html). Whether this is a good idea or not depends on how frequently you will access the objects and what degree of latency your application can tolerate.